# There is a table of the complexity of recursive algoritms?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have a exam tomorrow and the teacher allow us to consult anthing that we want.

So i thinking if exist any "table" that show the theta and big-oh for some common recursive formulas.

Comment: Check out the "Master theorem".

Comment: Even I think this is not the type of question expected here, I suggest you read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Comment: Off-topic here, not research-level.

Comment: I removed the [complexity-classes] tag.  Just in case, it does not mean courses in complexity theory.

Answer (score 1):

Just to take this of the unanswered question list: Many recursive formulas can be solved using the Master theorem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem.